# When retrieving a set with EFCore, why do the retrieved entities not include their relationships to other objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

While using Entity Framework Core with SQL Server I encountered an unexpected problem. I have an entity A that has a one-to-many relationship on entity B.

```
 [Table("client")]
    public class Client
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; } = new LinkedList<Configuration>();
    }
```

I get a list of instances of entity A from the database like this:

```
public ICollection<Client> GetAllClients()
{
    return _dbContext.Clients.ToList();
}
```

When I call this function I get a list of instances without the instances of entity B in the relationship. Why are the objects in the relationship not retrieved correctly?

I've also found out that if I add this line of code to the function the entities are retrieved as expected.

```
public ICollection<Client> GetAllClients()
{
    var test = _dbContext.Configurations.ToList();
    return _dbContext.Clients.ToList();
}
```

This makes no sense to me. What am I missing here?

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related reference/collection properties must either be eagerly or explictly loaded. You generally want to eagerly load using `Include`:

```
var clients = await _context.Clients.Include(x => x.Configurations).ToListAsync();
```

Alternatively, you can lazy load, but that's generally a bad idea, as it can lead to N+1 query problems (i.e. you issue one query, and then a separate additional query for each item as you iterate through, which is obviously highly inefficient). Regardless, lazy loading requires two things:

1. The reference/collection property must have the `virtual` keyword. EF adds lazy loading functionality by creating a dynamic proxy of your entity class and overriding the property getter. Overriding, of course, can only be done on virtuals.
2. You have to explicitly add the lazy-loading services:

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => o.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
       .UseSqlServer(connectionString));
   ```

It works when you query the configurations as well, because EF has object-fixup. In other words, it will automatically fill related reference/collection properties, if it has previously retrieved those objects already and has them in its object cache. Otherwise, and if you do not otherwise load the relations, the property will remain null.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Include method to specify related data to be included in query results (Eager loading).

Take a look in the following example:

```
public ICollection<Client> GetAllClients()
{
    return _dbContext.Clients.Include(x => x.Configurations).ToList();
}
```

You can check the [MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading).